# HTML/CSS div disappearing after resizing browser to 960px

Tags: html, css, resize, adobe, muse

I'm currently working on my photography webpage. When resizing the browser down, all the html disappears from 960px downwards and shows nothing but a grey background.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

*Copied the code the best I could from adobe muse.*

CSS.

```
#outer_wrapper {  
width: auto;
height: 560px;
overflow-x: hidden;  
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 auto;}

#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper {
width:15000px;}

#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper.box {
width: auto;
height: 560px;
float: left;
margin: 0 15px 0 0;
border:0.0px white solid;}

#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper.boxV { 
width: auto;
height: 560px;
float: left;
margin: 0 15px 0 0;
border:0.0px white solid;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that when you make the innerwrapper have a width of 15000px, and then proceed to turn off white-space wrapping that the content is just being pushed way off to one side and is unable to be seen. Try getting rid of the `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` and see what happens if you scroll all the way through the containers to see the content. Also, using `overflow: hidden` prevents the user from scrolling at all, which probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your response! I'm not sure what I did but I think it worked!

Comment: @Chevy-JordanOphili Well, It is good that it works, but you should definitely aim to understand it for the next times!